# JSON object not being accessed using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am just unable to access values from the my json string (image below).

```
{
    all: [{
        info: {
            name: "Fahad",
            lat: "41.954815",
            lon: "-87.647209"
        }
    }, {
        info: {
            name: "Fahad",
            lat: "41.954815",
            lon: "-87.647209"
        }
    }, {
        info: {
            name: "Fahad",
            lat: "41.954815",
            lon: "-87.647209"
        }
    }],
    rowsfound: "11"
}
```

I am using angularjs, here is html

```
<ul ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        {{post.all[0].info.name}}  <em>{{post.rowsfound}}</em>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("PostsCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(myurl)
        .success(function (data) {
        $scope.posts = data;

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

two list items generated without any value.
whats the wrong thing am I doing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you console.log data and paste the exact result here?

Comment: As suggested by Mathew, your data might be wrapped in another object. You should console.log it and see what it looks like. Could be something like `data.results` to access your posts.

Comment: Answer below done that. Checked console.log, but original data is pvt. so can't paste here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this html:

```
<ul ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts.all">
        {{post.info.name}}  <em>{{posts.rowsfound}}</em>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON representation is wrong, correct is "name": "Fahad" etc.
You can use tools like http://jsonlint.com/ to check if your JSON is valid.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that the a lot of services returning like the same, so I can't go and correct at the moment but to use as is.